# Unable to create a jar file with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, executable-jar

Hi imported a code from git, and the code runs when I run the main class. However, I am not able to create a jar file.
I added this to the parent build.gradle:

```
    classifier 'fat'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'SampleClient'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF'
}
```

When I run using

```
./gradlew clean fatjar
```

it creates a jar file in the .out folder. But the jar does not seem to contain any class files

```
jar -tf <Folder>/.out/libs/testJob-1.6.0.17-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

When I run the jar, it gives a "no main class found" error

```
java -jar <Folder>/.out/libs/testJob-1.6.0.17-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class SampleClient
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.

There are three modules in the entire package

[image]

And the main class -- SampleClient is in the example module.

Any pointers would be helpful. And ask any question and I am OK to share the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create a separate gradle task and try the same,There are multiple ways to do that ref: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

```
task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Application-path'
    }
    baseName = 'jar-name'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Replace the applicate path in main-class and baseName as jar name.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: what grade command you are running after creating the custom task.